# What is the difference between parameters in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm required to handle different types of parameters in the @RequestMapping of the controller.  For example, how do you differentiate between

```
/posts
/posts/1
/posts&userId=1
```

This seems to work between the first two but calling the third one results in "Ambiguous mapping" error.

Here is the controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value= {"/posts", "/posts/{numberOfPosts}"})
public String getBlogPosts(@PathVariable Optional<Integer> numberOfPosts) { //to prevent "Ambiguous mapping" error
    if (numberOfPosts.isPresent()) {
        return blogService.getUserBlogPosts(numberOfPosts);
    }
    else {
        return blogService.getAllBlogPosts();
    }
}
```

Here is the third one:

```
@RequestMapping("/posts")
public String getUserIdPosts(@RequestParam int userId) {
    return blogService.getUserIdPosts(userId);
    //return blogService.getUserBlogPosts(numberOfPosts);
}
```

How do I handle the third one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path mapping for `/post` and `/post&userId=1` are the same: `/post`.

You can handle make the difference between these two URLs in your code by testing on the `userId` variable like below:

```
@RequestMapping(value= {"/posts", "/posts/{numberOfPosts}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getBlogPosts(@PathVariable(required = false) Optional<Integer> numberOfPosts, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer userId) {
    if (numberOfPosts.isPresent()) {
        return blogService.getUserBlogPosts(numberOfPosts);
    }
    else if(userId == null) {
        return blogService.getAllBlogPosts();
    } else {
        return blogService.getUserIdPosts(userId);
    }
}
```

Don't forger to make the requested parameter `userId` and the path variable  `numberOfPosts` optional by adding `required = false` to the above annotations.

Comment: can you tell me exactly what the first two lines should be?  I can't seem to get any combination to work

Comment: I have edited the answer, by making also the path variable optional.
The first two lines could be: 
@RequestMapping(value= {"/posts", "/posts/{numberOfPosts}"})
public String getBlogPosts(@PathVariable(required = false) Integer numberOfPosts, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer userId)

Comment: I pasted in the first 2 lines exactly as you have it but now "isPresent" is underlined and says "The method isPresent() is undefined for type Integer"

Comment: Right, numberOfPosts is of type Optional so the second line could be:
public String getBlogPosts(@PathVariable(required = false) Optional<Integer> numberOfPosts, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer userId)

Comment: Well now it compiles, but when I call it like this: $.get("/posts/1", function(data) {..., I get a 500 error in the browser.  And in the IDE console it says "404 Not Found: [{}]"

Comment: What is the raised exception in your application?

Comment: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not Found: [{}]

Comment: Could you show me the path with 404 issue?

Comment: I've updated the post.  The EDIT section shows the error chain.

Comment: If you are trying with this path /posts&userId=1, you will get 404 return, because this is not the right way to use parameters in url, you should change it with /posts?userId=1

Comment: No I'm not doing that.  I updated the post to show how I am doing it.

Comment: Is your controller annotated also with @RequestMapping

Comment: Yes.  I found the problem.  Optional was being passed to the service so I did numberOfPosts.get() to get the actual value.  I will check your solution since it answered my original question.  Thanks so much for your help!